# Can i make my code shorter?

Tags: javascript

I have many functions for calculating some stats , and i need to recheck the value's every time but that is extra code and make's it harder to read , can i store the variable assignment in another function:

```
function MC () {
var check=document.getElementById('check').checked;

var ea=Number(document.form.ea.value),
    ed=Number(document.form.ed.value),
    pa=Number(document.form.pa.value),
    pd=Number(document.form.pd.value);

var hpSum = 0,spSum=0,eaSum=0,edSum=0,pdSum=0,paSum=0;

if(check){
    eaSum = ea + 11;
    edSum = ed + 17;
    pdSum = pd + 17;
    paSum = pa + 11;
} else {
    eaSum = ea - 11;
    edSum = ed - 17;
    pdSum = pd - 17;
    paSum = pa - 11;
}

    document.form.ea.value=eaSum;
    document.form.ed.value=edSum;
    document.form.pa.value=paSum;
    document.form.pd.value=pdSum;
};
```

NOTE:I am speaking for the variables:ea,ed,pa,pd and sum variables.

Answer (score 1):

You could try building an object of parameters:

```
function MC() {
  var check = document.getElementById('check').checked,
      keys = {
        "ea":11,
        "ed":17,
        "pd":17,
        "pa":11
      }, i;
  for( i in keys) { if( keys.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
    document.form[i].value = +document.form[i].value + (check ? keys[i] : -keys[i]);
  }}
}
```

Note that `+somevar` is a cheap shortcut for `parseFloat(somevar)`. `Number(somevar)` is NOT the same as it creates a wrapper object that may interfere with comparisons if you add any in later.

Comment: also note that `check` is local, `keys` and `i` are global

Comment: will this be the best solution since i have 60+ relics like MC (+stats and some give ea,ed some pa pd , some hp and so on) ?

Comment: You could pass that `keys` object as a parameter instead of it being hardcoded into the function, then you can call `MC` to adjust whatever you need.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with your own code, condensed a bit. Assuming form is the name of a form, it would take more code to keep track which inputs have changed than to read them.

```
function MC () {
    var f= document.form,
    v= document.getElementById('check').checked? [11, 17]:[-11, -17];
    f.ea.value= Number(f.ea.value)+v[0];
    f.ed.value= Number(f.ed.value)+v[1];
    f.pa.value= Number(f.pa.value)+v[0];
    f.pd.value= Number(f.pd.value)+v[1];
}
```